# Getting ORA-01002:fetch out of sequence error when doing Bulk-collect

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sys-refcursor, bulk-collect

In the below example , I have a SP which will return a SYS_REFCURSOR as OUT parameter to the Java service, and in the same SP it will insert the SYS_REFCURSOR result to another table example -temp. When I execute the SP, it gives an error

> ORA-01002 : fetch out of sequence error

I do see the data getting inserted but the service is not returning back any REFCURSOR to the service.

```
create or replace procedure ins_act(l_result        OUT        sys_refcursor)
as 

 --Created a RECORD type to hold the result of the SYS_REFCURSOR
 TYPE RSLT IS RECORD
 (

 l_id1                   varchar2(32),
 l_id2                   varchar2(32),
 l_id3                   varchar2(32),
 l_pid                   varchar2(16),
 l_ac                    varchar2(32),
 l_activity_date         varchar2(32),
 l_file_id               varchar2(64)
 ) ;

 --Created associative array to hold the result
 Type v_reslt is table of RSLT index by PLS_INETEGER;

 --Variable to Record type
 var_reslt   v_reslt;

begin
          -- Procedure to pull the get records 
          OPEN l_result FOR 
             SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,CoUnt(*).....
             

          -- Bulk fetch
          Loop

          fetch l_result bulk collect into  var_reslt limit 100;         

          --Bulk Insert     
          FORALL I INTO 1..var_reslt.count SAVE EXCEPTIONS
          insert into temp(id1,
                           id2,
                           id3,
                           platform_id,
                           activity_code,
                           update_timestamp,
                           file_id)          
          values 
             (to_char(to_date(var_reslt(i).l_id1,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'mm/dd/yyyy'),
              var_reslt(i).l_id2,
              var_reslt(i).l_id3,
              0,
              var_reslt(i).l_ac,
              var_reslt(i).l_activity_date,
              var_reslt(i).l_file_id);

         exit when l_result%notfound; 

      end loop;

   Commit;

  close l_result;

Exception
 WHEN OTHERS
   THEN    
         --Bulk Exception handling
         FOR indx IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
         LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                  SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_INDEX
               || ‘: ‘
               || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_CODE);
         RAISE;          
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with this code.

The first is that you are checking whether the cursor found anything **after** the FORALL statement. This is wrong because the FORALL statement attempts to process the cursor even when the cursor is `%notfound`. That might be the source of your ORA-01002 exception.

The second error is a subtle one. Checking for cursor `%notfound` is a problem with LIMIT clause, because it will evaluates to `true` when the cursor returns any number of records less than the limit: it will be `%notfound` even if the cursor returns 99 records. This is a non-intuitive aspect of the PL/SQL implementation. Anyway, it is better to check the number of entries in the collection.

Here is your code fixed for these two issues:

```
create or replace procedure ins_act(l_result        OUT        sys_refcursor) as 

 TYPE RSLT IS RECORD  (
 l_id1                   varchar2(32),
 l_id2                   varchar2(32),
 l_id3                   varchar2(32),
 l_pid                   varchar2(16),
 l_ac                    varchar2(32),
 l_activity_date         varchar2(32),
 l_file_id               varchar2(64)) ;

 Type v_reslt is table of RSLT index by PLS_INETEGER;
 var_reslt   v_reslt;

begin
          OPEN l_result FOR 
             SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,CoUnt(*).....
          Loop

          fetch l_result bulk collect into  var_reslt limit 100;          
          
          exit when var_reslt.count() = 0; 

          --Bulk Insert     
          FORALL I INTO 1..var_reslt.count SAVE EXCEPTIONS
          insert into temp(id1,
                           id2,
                           id3,
                           platform_id,
                           activity_code,
                           update_timestamp,
                           file_id)          
          values 
(to_char(to_date(var_reslt(i).l_id1,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'mm/dd/yyyy'),
              var_reslt(i).l_id2,
              var_reslt(i).l_id3,
              0,
              var_reslt(i).l_ac,
              var_reslt(i).l_activity_date,
              var_reslt(i).l_file_id);
      end loop;
   Commit;
   close l_result;

Exception
 WHEN OTHERS
   THEN    
         --Bulk Exception handling
         FOR indx IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
         LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                  SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_INDEX
               || ‘: ‘
               || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_CODE);
         RAISE;          
end;
/
```

The final error is procedural. A refcursor is a one-time shot. You read it in the program, which means it is exhausted when you pass it back to the java layer. There are a couple of ways to resolve this, depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve. Post more details regarding your logic.

Comment: My requirement is return the sys_refcursor C1 to the service and insert the same sys_refcursor C1 into another table . i tried to make the above change mentioned, but still getting fetch out of sequence error

Comment: How close is your actual code to the code you posted? Obviously you've redacted the projection of the SELECT statement: have you simplified other bits, omitted loops, etc? Because it's hard to see how the posted code can throw an ORA-01002 (the thing I send could throw it was a guess: I haven't seen ORA-01002 caused by that particular means of invalidating a cursor).